# How to change the z-index of list items in a menu with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, menu, reverse

I am making a long menu for a wordpress theme and it appears on two rows. The problem is that the sub menu of the top row appears under the list items on the bottom row. My solution is to change the z-index but I don't know how many elements the menu will have so I am using jQuery. Here is the code but it doesn't work. Could you help?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var items;
    items=jQuery(".menu>ul>li").length;

    for (var i=0; i<items; i++){
        jQuery(".menu>ul>li").css("z-index", function( items, i ){
            return items - i;
        });
    }

},"jQuery");
```

Comment: means you need first li z-index 1, second li z-index 2 and third li z-index 3?

Comment: The other way around - I want the first element to be with the highest index and so on.

Comment: Why are you changing the "z-index" property of the elements? "z-index" is not the sorting index of the HTML elements. By W3Schools Definition it is like this: The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

Comment: means if we have 5 li then first li z-index should be 5?

Comment: I amended the question, I hope now it's clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to reverse the list, you can use:

```
var list = $('.menu>ul');
var items = list.children('li');
list.append(items .get().reverse());
```

This will reverse the order, so 1,2,3 becomes 3,2,1. `z-index` [relates to the display order in terms of visual 'layering'.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

> The z-index CSS property specifies the z-order of an element and its
>   descendants. When elements overlap, z-order determines which one
>   covers the other. An element with a larger z-index generally covers an
>   element with a lower one.

If you want to reverse `z-index` you can use:

```
var num= $('.menu>ul>li').length; /* or suitably high number depending on your layout */
$('.menu>ul>li').each(function(i, item) {
    $(item).css('z-index', num - i);
});
```

Comment: Maybe I asked the question not clearly enough. Actually I want the list items to appear in their normal order but the first to be on top of the next. I will amend the question!